# Why doesn't rstudio autocomplete the left_join() "by" columns when using pipes?

Tags: r, dplyr, autocomplete, rstudio, magrittr

Make a little example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- tibble(test = "test")
```

If I start typing it this way:

```
left_join(test, test, by = c(
```

I can press TAB at that point and Rstudio will drop in the column `"test"` with the quotes around it exactly how `left_join()` likes it. Very nice. I can mash "tab", "=", "tab" and bob's your uncle it's all done.

If I do it the pipes way, I get no such luxury.

```
test %>% left_join(test, by = c(
```

I'm mashing away at TAB and getting the little (No matches) popup.

Odd, becasue if I type:

```
test %>% filter(
```

and press TAB then I'm getting the column popping up in the drop-down just like one would expect.

Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing?

EDIT: screenshot after pressing tab:
[image]

Comment: The syntax in your pipes example is wrong - you supplied `test` twice as an argument to `left_join`. It should be `test %>% left_join(test, by = c(`. Auto-completion works for me when this is corrected.

Comment: I should add that auto-complete works for me even with the syntax error - so there may be something specific to your setup, such as the version of RStudio.

Comment: Same here, works for me.

Comment: I'm working on RStudio version 1.4.1103, on windows 10. R version 4.0.4. Which version / operating systems are you folks on?

Comment: I've tried on feora 1.4.1103 and I get the same thing - no matches. Just me then?!